# Send email with PHPMailer and rotate images

Tags: php, css, image, phpmailer

I am able to send emails with images using PHPMailer, but now I would like to rotate some of the images from landscape to portrait. Is it possible to rotate images using CSS in the email?

Comment: you can look into CSS transform property

Comment: Unfortunately, transform is automatically removed by either the email server or the email client.

Comment: CSS in email. Not likely unless its very basic CSS within the style attribute of HTML; Changing a font color at most. In the end, it's up to the mail server / provider if it decides to parse CSS.

Comment: I doubt there is anything you can do with code.  The presentation of photos in an email client is not defined in any standards.  I would however, take a look at the orientation exif data in the pictures themselves.    If that is not what you expect it could be due to the exif data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/transforms/transform/), the CSS [`transform:rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) property is not supported in the majority of the top Desktop, Mobile, and Webmail email clients.

Instead, a more dependable method would be to simply rotate the images manually in advance, or use the PHP function [`imagerotate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) to rotate the images to landscape programmatically before sending the email.